# Bukkit - Change block on click (client side)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

What I'm trying to do is to replace a block into a diamond block on client side when a player right clicks it

```
public class setBlock implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockClick(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        if (event.getHand()== EquipmentSlot.HAND) {
            Player player = event.getPlayer();
            BlockData block = Material.DIAMOND_BLOCK.createBlockData();
            Location loc = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
            player.sendBlockChange(loc, block);
        }
    }
}
```

Can I get some help please?

Comment: What do you mean with "don't work" ? what is your issue exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check if you clicked right and if the location of the clicked block is even not null.

```java
public class setBlock implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockClick(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        if (event.getClickedBlock() == null) return;

        if (event.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
            Player player = event.getPlayer();
            BlockData block = Material.DIAMOND_BLOCK.createBlockData();
            Location loc = event.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
            player.sendBlockChange(loc, block);
        }
    }
}
```